# Is public transportation necessary in Madrid?

Tags: public-transport, europe, spain, western-europe, madrid

Flying in about a month to Madrid with my family :)

Usually when I'm abroad I get the unlimited public transport weekly ticket and use it a lot.
From researching a bit online and viewing the map, it seems that almost all of the places we're planning to visit so far (Restaurants, Puerta del Sol, Plaza de España, San Miguel, etc.) are only 10-15 minutes walk away from our hotel (located next to Primark in Gran Via).

Will public transportation even be necessary for us in Madrid? or is it better to walk?

Are all of the interesting places actually that close to the city center? Or perhaps I'm missing out on some...

Thanks!

Comment: I spent a few days in Madrid three years ago. I used the Hop on Hop Off bus. If the locations you plan to visit are within 15 minutes of your hotel, you don't need to get public transport. For me I visited some places like the Almudena cemetery which were too far to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't know if there are any (for you) interesting places out of reach of your acceptable walking distance. The answer is purely opinion based and I have therefore voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine just walking, most of the interesting places are within walking distance. In case you need it, you can always buy a 10 ticket subway card.

edit: I live in Madrid.